# How to modify the createOrder of the paypal in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, paypal, payment

Hello guys I have a template like this :

```
 <div id="smart-button-container">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      <div>
        Total Cost: {{ calculatedCost }}$
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

that brings me the TotalCost .

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters("events", ["getEvent"]),
    calculatedCost() {
      return this.getEvent.totalCost / 10;
    }
  }
```

It gets calcuated from here .
In my createOrder inside the paypal method I got this :

```
 createOrder: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                currency_code: 'EUR',
                value: this.calculatedCost
              }
            }]
          });
        },
```

But it returns me wrong format and it doesnt accept it. Any ideas? The calcuatedCost comes like a String number . Ive tried to format it to number but it has the same result

Answer (score 0):

What does it return? Maybe you need `this.calculatedCost()`

In any case, such a client-side `actions.order.create` and `actions.order.capture` are deprecated and should not be used for any new integration.

See [the standard checkout documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) for information on having your button code call server-side routes, which you must implement on a server and should in turn call the /v2/checkout/orders API.

Comment: ok i will follow your link. It returns a number but i dont know if it accept methos in there because when i tried : value: 1 it worked good and returned me 1 euro

Comment: methos? functions usually need to be called to get a value. But anyway, the amount shouldn't be set in client-side code; use a server route and the /v2/checkout/orders API